# Make gif with timeline in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gif

My question is simple: I have been using time line before that looks like this 
[image]
but now it looks like this

[image]

How can i get it back so it looks like in the first picture?

Answer (score 2):

Go to the **Timeline Window Menu Options** and select **Convert to Video Timeline**

[image]